# How to use csscss with guard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, guard

I’d like to use csscss tool to detect duplicated CSS in Rails environment. My end goal is to run it whenever a commit is added (and detecting duplicates is only a first step), but assume the simpler case: making csscss go with guard.

I have not found any plugins to handle that nor I have experience to create one.

Did anyone find similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Guard-Shell](https://github.com/guard/guard-shell) to execute `csscss` on every stylesheet modification:

```
guard :shell do
  watch /app/assets/stylesheets/(.*)/ do |m|
    `csscss #{ m[0] }`
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I’m going to try this out as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about Gruntjs?

There is a good wrapper for cscscs in the gruntjs:
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-csscss

I think, watch task + csscss task is the good decision.

link to the watch task: 
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we use Guard to automate many tasks in the project. I don’t want to introduce another dependency. :)